# UILabel set text vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a UILabel that I want to expand vertically rather than horizontally after some maximumWidth. Currently I am trying to do this by doing the following:

```
    _caption.numberOfLines = 0;
    _caption.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

and then when I size I use `sizeToFit`

However, I always have a width that is much larger than my maximumWidth.

I tried using `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` but this did not work.

I could do a simple calculation by dividing the width by the maximumWidth that I want and then adjust the height accordingly but I'm wondering if there is any way to do this automatically.

Comment: As i see, with your code you are doing right way. But make sure you don't set height constraint for you label or do something make you label's height can't be changed

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`instead of `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`

```
_caption.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping
```

I had tested this using a simple label and storyboard and setting the constraints to top, left and width and here is the result

[image]